# Rate of growth between two given complexities

Tags: complex-analysis, algorithms, computational-complexity

I stumbled upon this questions while studying about complexities.
So how should I go about finding a growth rate between two given complexities, say

Between 
$$O(\sqrt n ) \quad \text{and} \quad O(n)$$ 
For this I think the answer is $$f(n)= n^{\frac{3}{4}}$$

or

Between
$$ O(n\cdot log(n)) \quad \text{and} \quad O(n^{2})$$

Answer (score 1):

Your $f(n)$ is correct.

For the other question you can apply the same trick, so $f(n)=n\sqrt{n}\log(n)$.

See this link for more knowledge:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Table_of_common_time_complexities

Comment: Awesome! thanks a lot. So, I just need to find a function that is between the given complexities? right?
But what happens if I am given two complexities, say, factorial and exponential? What would I need to do then